# Unity2D C# - Can't destroy an Instantiated object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class playerAttack : MonoBehaviour {

public bool attacking = false;

public Transform Player;
public Transform swordObject_prefab;
Animator anim;

GameObject clone = null;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (!attacking && !anim.GetBool ("isSwimming"))
            attackCode ();
    if (attacking)
        coolDown ();
}

void attackCode(){

    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("AttackA")) {
        Debug.Log ("ATTACK_A");
        anim.SetBool ("isAttackingA", true);
        attacking = true;
        clone = (GameObject)Instantiate(swordObject_prefab, Player.position, Quaternion.identity);
        Destroy(clone);

    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("AttackB")) {
        anim.SetBool ("isAttackingB", true);
    }

}

void coolDown(){
    if (!anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName ("SwordSwing")) {
        attacking = false;
        anim.SetBool ("isAttackingA", false);

    }
}
```

Here's my code.
Im trying to get it so when the player presses a button, he swings a sword spawning at the players location. that all works fine, but when i try to remove the sword I get this error in Unity:

InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
playerAttack.attackCode () (at Assets/Scripts/Player/playerAttack.cs:33)
playerAttack.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Player/playerAttack.cs:22)

Thanks for the advice.

By the way, if anyone knows of a better way to use weapons in Unity2D I will be open to suggestions if this way is a cumbersome way of doing things.

Comment: I would store the weapons in a inactive gameobject as child of the character. Instead of instantiate an object and destory it I would go with gameobject.setactive(true/false). You will save a lot of performance in your game. Short answer to your last line of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must instantiate prefabs like this.

```
PrefabTypeObject obj = (TypeOfPrefab)Instantiate(prefab, position, rotation);
```

or

```
PrefabTypeObject obj = Instantiate(prefab, position, rotation) as TypeOfPrefab;
```

otherwise you will get null object or InvalidCastException like now.

Your solution is`

```
clone = (GameObject)Instantiate(swordObject_prefab.gameObject, Player.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
public Transform swordObject_prefab;
```

To this:

```
public GameObject swordObject_prefab;
```

But I'm not sure what instantly destroying an object that has been just created is for...  Maybe you want to use a delay?

```
Destroy(clone, 2f); // Destroy clone 2 seconds from now
```